# Repeated review audit (5 times so far)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

I was reviewing posts in the First questions review queue in Ask Ubuntu.

Take a look at this:

[image: Screenshot of my review history]

I had to do the same review audit twice. The links of the review tasks are:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1201243
- https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1201250

If we take a look at the timeline link of the posts in the audits, it is the same: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1386965/timeline

Considering the fact that we have a shortage of reviewers in Ask Ubuntu (or at least that's what I feel), it is worrisome that reviewers need to go through the same audit twice. It's a waste of time.

Please fix this bug.

---

#### Update 1

I had do to the same review audit twice today:

- https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1203152
- https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1203161

---

#### Update 2

I had to do the [same review audit](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-questions/1204521) again today.

So that makes it [five times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQt7A.png). TBH, I am annoyed now.

Comment: The [same thing happened to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321832/6083675), but that's how it works. Also discussed in [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315848/6083675) with a response from someone who was an employee at the time.

Comment: @Laurel That was 2016. It's been 6 years. I hope they fix it at least now.

Comment: @RandomPerson as linked by Laurel this is not a bug, but [tag:status-by-design].

Comment: @Luuklag I am not really sure if it is status-by-design since the tag was not used in the post. Anyway, something which was status-by-design can be reconsidered.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to file a feature request asking to change the design in response to an employee stating that something is by design. But that would be a feature request, not a bug report, as *bug* means that something isn't working as per the design. As far as why the tag wasn't used on that post, it's because it was a support question asking if it was by design, to which the answer was yes, and not a bug report; the [tag:status-bydesign] tag is only for bug reports per its extended tag wiki.

Comment: That same post [was used as a review audit 26 times](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19924/why-is-the-pool-of-selectable-known-bad-first-question-audits-so-small?noredirect=1#comment44666_19924) overall, for all users.

Comment: The review queues got adjusted, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315848/same-audit-showed-up-again/420274#420274

Comment: @marrados feel free to repost that answer here