# Review Audit with a "Pending Edit" - What happens if I approve the edit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Earlier today, I was presented with [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/30911596) in the First Questions review queue on Stack Overflow. (Actually, I have been given that audit *twice* today, within a 20 minute time-frame, and *four times* over the past few days.)

Although I spotted this audit for what it was (the "Haskell" tag is generally a good indicator), what interests me here is that, at the time of the audits (today), there was a "Pending edit" on the post (and still is, at the time of posting this).

If I recall correctly, attempting to "Edit" such a "known good" audit will fail the test; but what would happen, in such a case, if I were to open the pending suggested edit and "Approve" that (assuming I were the second such reviewer to do so)? I would then, effectively, be *applying* an edit to the post *while it was an audit*. Would that also fail the test? Or would it simply not be considered part of the audit, and be as if I had opened the post in a separate window and edited it from there?

To avoid such confusion, should posts with pending suggested edits even be 'allowed' as audits?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're forced to go to the suggested edits queue, which doesn't count towards your original review. But that's based on [what happens with real reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148004/323179), so no guarantees that it applies to audits. I think you should have tried it when you had the opportunity.

Comment: @Laurel Well, the second time (today), I did click the "Pending edit" button (from the audit) ... and it *did* take me to the same place as with a real review (i.e. a mini edit-review dialog box). However, I didn't complete that spin-off review.

Comment: Not sure if it's still the case, but 1º [if you press edit you're effectively taken out of the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369532). 2º Then, being served the same item twice after having pressed skip wasn't supposed to happen but after the review queues redesign it does happen occasionally (at least it did a month ago). 3º How this all factors in when you come across an audit is a good Q, I suppose the best way to finding out is getting a userscript that says it's an audit and skipping enough of them until by chance one with a pending suggested edit comes along (there may be none).

Comment: @bad_coder On (1) - Yes, but if I then approve, leave that 'spawned' edit review queue, go back to the audit and "refresh", I may have then applied the edit while I'm (still) facing the audit. Therein lies my confusion.

Comment: @AdrianMole that alone is a good question, do edits retain original pending suggested edits? Do subsequent suggested edits show on audits? And does the approval count as a review action? I'm guessing that's more business complexity than was implemented, so the most likely answer is that the actions are independent; but it would have to be tested.

Comment: Regarding repeated review audit, check this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375430